# Can somebody give an example of configuring Spring JDBC fast connection failover AOP?

Tags: spring-jdbc, failover

I try to use Spring JDBC data extention package to do fast connection failover with Oracle database. I'm having a problem to configure the AOP part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure UCP (Universal Connection Pool) with Spring. Take a look at this blog [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ucp-with-spring-framework).